# How to animate letters/words on screen in different ways

Tags: ios, android-animation, ios-animations

I know How to use/show animated images in `ImageView`. But I m wondering if this is possible in native iOS and/Or Android that *letters* of a `string` can be shown on screen via different shape of animations.

> For Example:
>
> Ballons on the full app screen pop and deposit the words of the text/string.
>
> Popcorn in a pan on the full app screen pop and deposits the words of the text/string.

Then these letters/words are moving down to bottom of app screen and placed/shown in some `textView`

I have searched a lot but found nothing like this in Native environment.

I have found [THIS LTMorphingLabel](https://github.com/lexrus/LTMorphingLabel)  but it is very far from my requirement.

Any idea or direction will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Lottie](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android) is a mobile library for Android and iOS that parses Adobe
>   After Effects animations exported as json with Bodymovin and renders
>   them natively on mobile!

you can have different animation for each lettter

have fun

Comment: Thanks Mehrad!  Let me study this and then I will back to you